# What happens to the Merge-Sort algorithm when med is changed from (ini + end) /2 to ini + (end-ini)/4?

Tags: java, algorithm

Concerning the following form of the Merge-Sort algorithm:

```
    public static void merge(int [] a, int ini, int med, int end){

    int [] b = new int[end - ini + 1];
    int i = ini;
    int j = med + 1;
    int k = 0;

    while(i <= med && j <= end) {

        if(a[i] <= a[j]){

            b[k] = a[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {

            b[k] = a[j];
            j++;
        }

        k++;
    }

    while(i <= med) {

        b[k] = a[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while(j <= end) {

        b[k] = a[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    for(k = 0; k < b.length; k++){

        a[ini + k] = b[k];
    }
}

public static void mergeSortRec(int [] a, int ini, int end){

    if(ini < end){

        int med = (ini + end) / 2;

        mergeSortRec(a, ini, med);
        mergeSortRec(a, med + 1, end);
        merge(a, ini, med, end);
    }
}

public static void mergeSort(int [] a){

    mergeSortRec(a, 0, a.length - 1);
}
```

I have to identify what performance differences will be made to the merge method if I change the med variable inside mergeSortRec from (ini + end) /2 to ini + (end-ini)/4.

I tried evaluating the algorithm asymptotically, and found out that on the former the merge goes in O(n) and mergeSortRec goes as O(ln n) (so the algorithm is a O(n ln n), but I couldn't evaluate how it stands on the new form.

What is the difference to Merge method performance when the change is made?
To the algorithm as a whole, is there any real difference?

I am attempting to see which of the two would be more efficient (I known it probably is the n/2 one) as a practice, but I'm not able to evaluate it

Comment: `is there any real difference?` - you seem to be on a promising track - please show how far you got `evaluating the algorithm "asymptotically"` and `as a practice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break the problem in two parts (instead of two equal parts) one part is one fourth of initial and second is (3/4)th of original problem then your recursion tree will go deeper for the second part and hence it will increase the running time.

Below is the underlying mathematics-

T(N) = T(N/4) + T(3*N/4)

```
 = T(N/16) + T(3*N/16) + T(3*N/16) + T(9*N/16)
 = T(N/16) + 2*T(3*N/16) + T(N*(3/4)*(3/4))
                ...
                ...
```

from here you can see that recursive calls will end when some power of (3/4) will be equal to or exceed N.

(3/4)^x = N

x = logN on base 3/4

Now you can compare the graph of logN on base 2 and logN on base 3/4 and understand why dividing in two equal parts has better asymptotic behaviour.

[This is recursion tree for an array of size 16 with your mid as ini + (end-ini)/4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWFUc.jpg)

P.S. Read text books for understanding aymptotic analysis. It will help you a lot.

Comment: Your recurrence relation is missing the linear term that comes up from the merge step - it completely changes the math and the resulting runtime.

Comment: @templatetypedef I agree that recurrence relation is missing linear term and my rationale for leaving that is to make things simpler and show that recurrence depth is changing, merge procedure remains same and hence the analysis remains same for that.